# How can I enter a literal prime symbol (′) in XML with XSLT (docbook)?

Tags: xml, xslt, docbook

Whenever there is a prime symbol (′) in my XML, XSL transforms it into something very strange looking:

[image: weird subscript]

I.e. subscripted, outside of the block element where it shouldn't be.

I think that's because something in docbook or XSL has some sort of special behavior associated with that symbol. But using the entity code `&prime;` instead of ′ gets the same results! What could be causing this, and how do I enter a literal ′ symbol?

Comment: How can this be reproduced? Can you show us the XML markup that produces the bad output?

Comment: That's the weird thing. There is no special markup that does this--no XML tags around `807′.2` that are any different from the surroundings. So there must be something about the prime symbol that's throwing everything off. When the prime symbol is removed, everything's OK again. To reproduce, put a prime symbol in some XML that's transformed using Docbook XSL-FO.

Comment: `<para role="citation" id="A5c1" remap="d1e834">Altick, Richard D., and John J.
                  Fenstermaker. <citetitle>The Art of Literary Research</citetitle>. 4th ed. New
                  York: Norton, 1993. 353 pp. PR56.A68 807′.2.</para>` i.e. no xml markup around `807′.2`. that would make it display differently.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem. What version of DocBook-XSL do you use? Do you have a customization layer that does something special with `para` elements that contain citations?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two possibilities worth investigating.

(a) there's some transcoding problem: the prime is output as some binary code which is interpreted by the receiving code as a formatting directive for subscripting

(b) the prime character itself acts as a formatting directive.

Either way, the problem is to do with whatever software it is that renders the stream of bytes output by the XSLT processor as pixels on your screen or printer. Since you haven't told us anything about what this rendering software is, it's hard to help.